# Function argument explanation

Tags: c++

```
void print(std::ostream& out=std::cout) const
{
    for(int i = 0; i < _items.size(); i++)
    {
        out << _items[i] << " ";
    }

}
```

What does the `std::ostream& out=std::cout` in the function's argument mean?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::ostream&` is the type of the parameter, a reference to a `std::ostream` object.

`out` is the name of the parameter

`=std::cout` means that the default argument for the parameter is set to `std::cout`

Thus, you can call `print` as: `print()` and the argument will be `std::cout` by default